# twitter application in tweet box

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, twitter

I want to know about the twitter status update from any one of the particular website. Currently as I am working with twitter status update, It's working fine. My question is: If I tweet anything in this tweet box it goes to this (http://t.co/fhlgeXf) URL. If I visited to on my twitter account it has been updated by that url: http://t.co/fhlgeXf.

But, I want that, the tweets  go to my website URL with given my application name.. I have created API console which I created for via...

So finally I need the every updates go with my url link and my application via.

How can i get this?

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to ask....

Comment: You should show some code, and what result you want to achieve. I don't understand either

Comment: i used that belo code   <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
   <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button"
      data-via="twitterapi"
      data-text="Checking out this page about Tweet Buttons"
      data-related="anywhere:The Javascript API"
      data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the twitter's tweet box, all url's will be shortened with twitter's t.co url shortener. It will not allow you to include your original url there. This is actually a safety measure so that they can stop any rogue spam apps from spreading.
2. To tweet your links and have the 'via application', you will have to use twitter's OAuth implementation. There is a client side javascript API that you can use. Also there is a server side implementation that you may want to look into.